# How to partition a dataframe on multiple columns and write the output to xlsx in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, partitioning

I'm new to scala and I don't know how to ask this kind of question (technical word ...). I have a dataframe :

```
id     VehicleID         Longitude    Latitude     Date         Distance
1       12311            55.55431     25.45631     01/02/2020    20
2       12311            55.55432     25.45634     01/02/2020    80
3       12311            55.55433     25.45637     02/02/2020    10
4       12311            55.55431     25.45621     02/02/2020    50
5       12309            55.55427     25.45627     01/02/2020    30
6       12309            55.55436     25.45655     02/02/2020    20
7       12412            55.55441     25.45657     01/02/2020    14
8       12412            55.55442     25.45656     02/02/2020    60
```

i want to save each partition by vehicle_id and date in a different file.
**For Exampe**

```
 Save tha on a xlsx file named : 12311_01/02/2020

 id     VehicleID         Longitude    Latitude     Date         Distance
 1       12311            55.55431     25.45631     01/02/2020    20
 2       12311            55.55432     25.45634     01/02/2020    80

 Save tha on a xlsx file named : 12311_02/02/2020

 id     VehicleID         Longitude    Latitude     Date         Distance
 3       12311            55.55433     25.45637     02/02/2020    10
 4       12311            55.55431     25.45621     02/02/2020    50

 Save tha on a xlsx file named : 12309_01/02/2020

 id     VehicleID         Longitude    Latitude     Date         Distance
 5       12309            55.55427     25.45627     01/02/2020    30
```

I managed to save it in a single file, but I cannot save in several files according to partition

```
df.cache().write.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").option("header",true).save("test.xlsx")
```

**There is any posibility to do that on spark with scala ?**

Thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to partition your dataframe on two columns, all you have to do is to call `partitionBy()` in order create more partitions and finally save the file to `csv`.

---

The following should do the trick for you:

```
df \
  .write \
  .partitionBy("VehicleID", "Date")
  .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel") \
  .option("header", "true") \
  .save("test.xlsx") \
```

---

Alternatively, if you want the output to be in `csv` format:

```
df \
  .write \
  .partitionBy("VehicleID", "Date")
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv") \
  .option("header", "true") \
  .save("test.csv") \
```

Comment: when I tried to save a dataframe to csv file it works very well , but when I saved it to xlsx file ,it shows me this error  '' Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded "" . Any idea ? thank you

Comment: Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds]